# How can I print this in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

The output window is filled with '?' marks.

```
select ('все магазины Сильпо') as test
```

I want the exact same text in the output window. I am using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `N` prefix to identify `unicode` character :

```
SELECT N'все магазины Сильпо' AS test
```

`N` actually stands for National language character set.

To quote from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

Comment: doesnt work. It gives error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: *Where* are you executing this to get that error? the statement above is perfectly correct?

Comment: @AlexK. - you would see this if you executed `SELECT n'все магазины Сильпо' AS test` - looks like for some reason the OP is using lower case `n` and then complaining the answers don't work

Comment: @DaxeshRadadiya. . .  Make sure you tested same code, i suspect you have defined prefix `n`  instead of `N`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time everyone.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define your string literal as a `nvarchar`, not a `varchar`:

```
PRINT N'все магазины Сильпо';
```

Comment: Doesnt work. It gives error: Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The name "n" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: @DaxeshRadadiya - it needs to be upper case `N`